# Twig can't find extension... what namespace should I use?

Tags: twig, composer-php

I am passing a BASE64 encoded string to a twig template that I would like to have a twig extension de-code.

I installed twig with composer and I'm not using any other frameworks and most of the extension examples I've found seem to assume you are, and I think that that is causing me trouble. I can't seem to get twig to find my extension.

So I think I'm having a name space issue. my setup:

```
root/
    -index.php
    -vendor/
            -twig/
```

Given this setup, where should I put the extension file and what name space should be at the top of the file? What is the proper way to load it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you register the extension with twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app isn't too complex, you can simply add extension in place where you register and load Twig itself.

```php
// index.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));

// an anonymous function:
$base64Decode = new Twig_Filter('base64_decode', function ($string) {
    return base64_decode($string);
});

// or a simple PHP function:
$base64Decode = new Twig_Filter('base64_decode', 'base64_decode');

// add the function to your Twig environment:
$twig->addFilter($base64Decode);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and I can see your thinking... seems logical BUT when I run it, I get a twig error Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "base64_decode" filter. In my template I have {{i.extra|base64_decode}}

Comment: Oh! I think I see whats wrong! You code uses "function" but I think I need to use "filter" correct?